# How to pass form input to ctools modal

Tags: forms, ajax, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I have a regular Drupal form that is not in a modal. When the user submits the form, a ctools modal popup opens (as per http://drupal.org/node/1482968).

My question is, what is the best method for passing form input to the modal? So that e.g. if the user enters their name ("Alex") in the form, the modal popup can read, "Welcome Alex!" ?

I am using Drupal 7 and the latest stable release of Ctools. (Also, I've asked this question in the ctools issue queue at http://drupal.org/node/1556856, but haven't had a reply in twenty days.) I've been trying to crack this one for a while, so would be incredibly grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just grabbing the passed variables from $_GET.